# Matrix's signature problem (about Hermitian matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

Say $M=M^{*}$ is an n*n Hermitian matrix with rank = r.
The question is how to determine the signature of the $2n*2n$ block matrix
\begin{matrix} 0 & M \\ M & 0 \end{matrix}

If we start with small n, it is apparent we can find the pattern that the signature should be things like (r,r,0), however, I'm not sure exactly what is the clearest way to show that in a general case.

Comment: you can check that $\text{trace}\big(A^k\big) = 0$ for odd $k$ and $\text{trace}\big(A^k\big) = 2\cdot M^*M = 2\cdot M^2$ for even k.  It immediately follows (e.g. by Newton's Identities) that $A$ has the same spectrum as $\begin{bmatrix}
M & \mathbf 0\\ 
\mathbf 0 & -M 
\end{bmatrix}$ which in turn gives you the signature.

Comment: Let $B$ be the block matrix, and let $Mv = \lambda v$ an eigenpair for the original matrix. Then $B(v, v) = \lambda(v, v)$ and $B(v, -v) = - \lambda (v, -v)$, where $(u, v)$ means the concatenation ("block vector") of the two vectors of length $n$. Therefore for each $\lambda$-eigenvector of the original matrix, you get a pair $\pm \lambda$ of eigenvalues of the new matrix. If the original signature is $(l, m, k)$ then the new signature is $(l + k, 2m, l + k)$.

Comment: @Joppy, That is what I did. And if we say the (P,Q,R) is the number of positive eigenspace, Q is negative, R is zero etc. Then we now know that, P=Q for the new matrix = rank of M which is r, and P+Q = Rank of this matrix = 2n - zero space of this matrix  = 2n - 2r. Which eventually gives (r,r,2n-2r) right?

Comment: Yes I think - I was using $(+, 0, -)$ for my signature whereas you are using $(+, -, 0)$. But you can see that the rank (sum of the positive and negative parts of the signature) of the new matrix is double the rank of the old matrix.